# Target dart2js failed No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, dart, github

I am running into an issue where on GH Actions my dart build is failing with lots of lines like

```
Compiling lib/main.dart for the Web...                          
Target dart2js failed: Exception: lib/api/file_a.dart:00:0:
Error: Error when reading 'lib/models/file_b.dart': Error reading 'lib/models/file_b.dart'  (No such file or directory)
import "/models/file_b.dart";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted to answer right away in case it helps someone else.

My issue was because I changed the capitalization of files in git. from `/File.dart` to `/file.dart`.

The way to fix this was for each import unable to be found to `git mv /File.dart /file.dart`